# How to add X Y Z coordinates to /testfor commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a money wars mini-game, and to upgrade the generators, you throw a certain ingot on the generator block, and then it upgrades it. I know you can put:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:whatever id}}
```

But where would I put the X Y Z coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax should work:

```
/testfor @e[x=a,y=b,z=c,r=1,type=Item]
```

Where `a` is the x co-ordinate, `b` is the y co-ordinate, and `c` is the z co-ordinate. Note that the `r=1` radius attribute is necessary to detect all items in the 1-block area, instead of only detecting items *at that exact co-ordinate*.

Example:

```
/testfor @e[x=25,y=64,z=79,r=1,type=Item]
```